# Leak at top of entry door jamb

Tags: doors, leak

So winter in Chicagoland is well upon us, and the snow at the top of the house is melting and we have a leak. The house entry point (well, the one we can see) is at the top of the jamb, between the screen/storm door and the entry door. It leaked enough that storm door was frozen shut.

As I see it, I have a roof leak. But it's winter and slippery, and will be quite some time before I can get someone to address that portion of it.

My question here is: How do I deal with the leak *now*?

The dripping water is affecting the operation of the door, and the water leaks out under the storm door and then coats my landing with ice. I need to do something for it, but caulking the leak area seems to me to just divert the water somewhere else within my walls. Is there any decent solution besides a bucket underneath 'til spring?

Comment: You are positive it is the roof and not the door installation? Not sure if your storm door was just recently installed.

Comment: You should probably just get your roof fixed now.  Chances of locating the leak when the entry point is iced over is slim.  Caulking will just force to water to leak elsewhere.  You really need to find out where the leak is and fix it!

Comment: @Rhea you may be right. There is a bit of a flatspot at the top of the frame, like a crown molding or a mantel. And luckily for me there's a seam right behind that. Some combination of cold, blowing, and ice may be pushing water to that seam. We'll see once it's warm enough to try caulking.

Comment: Cool. Hope it's the door!